# Different nmap results from different machines?

Tags: networking, server, email, firewall, nmap

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with my home Postfix mail server installed on Ubuntu Server not being able to reach gmail mail servers.  I have noticed that when I run nmap to the IP address 173.194.198.108 (gmail-smtp-mas.l.google.com) it shows different results from different machines (non-common ports highlighted in **bold**):

The problematic machine (home Postfix server on a wired Toronto-based ISP):

```
sudo nmap 173.194.198.108 -Pn (I have to run -Pn because it says host is non-responsive)
```

Ports open: 465 (smtps), 587 (submission), 993 (imaps), 995 (pop3s)

A Ubuntu VM, connected to wifi based in Chicago:

```
sudo nmap 173.194.198.108
```

Ports open: **25 (smtp)**, 465 (smtps), 587 (submission), 993 (imaps), 995 (pop3s)

A Ubuntu Server machine on wifi connected on phone hotspot to Toronto-based ISP:

```
sudo nmap 173.194.198.108
```

Ports open: **21 (ftp), 25 (smtp), 80 (http), 443 (https),** 465 (smtps), 587 (submission), 993 (imaps), 995 (pop3s), **8080 (http-proxy), 8081 (blackice-icecap)**

Unfortuantely, the first is the one that I want to connect to port 25.  Why is the same server showing different nmap results based on machine/location?  Could the individual ISP's be blocking certain ports, or does Google discriminate based on ISP/network settings?

The VM has Windows Defender but no other firewalls/security settings on the others that may be blocking this.  My home machine is behind a router with several forwarded ports to it if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're seeing is that many ISPs and network admins block all traffic on ports 21 and 25.

When you're on a network that doesn't allow traffic on those ports, the traffic gets dropped, therefore you don't see a response.

## Ports for Spam Bots

These ports are blocked because they are unauthenticated and used primarily for spam bots, not for modern programs.

SMTP with StartTLS runs on 465 and (sometimes) 587.

Secure FTP (SSH) runs on port 22.

## Portscanning

Also, be careful about running nmap. In the wrong crowd it's considered a crime.

- https://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html

Some networks will detect and block devices that run port scans.

Answer (score 1):

To configure Postfix for for Gmail, please use host-names instead of IPs.

---

For example to connect to Gmail's SMTP server, you need to use `smtp.gmail.com` and for IMAP you need to use `imap.gmail.com`

---

Yes, IP's will change based on your location and results may vary but host-names will work fine.

Please, refer to [this link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) for ports and additional configuration help.

---

**Please note:**

Insecure connections are not supported by and may not be used with Gmail servers

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My question is why are the nmap results different?  Shouldn’t what ports a server has open not change based on what machine is checking?  For example, smtp.gmail.com is showing port 25 is not listening when my server checks but when other machines check it port 25 is showing as open.

Comment: @GreatWhiteSlark Yes open ports results may differ based on location. This has to do with IP owner's service policy in each country. Please try different online nmap scan providers such as https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/ and https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap and others to see for yourself.